# SQL Server - Set a variable if a value from one table exists in another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables that are set up as shown below:

```
Table 1:  
ID      Name     Date
1       a         2000-01-01
2       b         2001-01-01
3       c         2002-01-01`

Table 2:
ID    Name
2       b
3       c
```

I would like to return all in Table 1 and then have a column that will hold a variable of either 'Yes' or 'No', based on whether they exist in Table 2, as shown below.

As shown:

```
Results:

Name   Date         Yes/No
  a    2000-01-01    No
  b    2001-01-01    Yes    
  c    2002-01-01    Yes
```

I have:

```
DECLARE @boolean as varchar(10)
IF EXISTS(
SELECT ID FROM Table 2
)
SET @boolean = 'Yes'  
ELSE SET @boolean = 'No'

SELECT Name, Date, @boolean as 'Yes/No'
FROM Table 1
LEFT JOIN Table 2 u ON Table 1.ID = Table 2.ID
```

However, this returns the results as shown below:

```
Name   Date         Yes/No
  a    2000-01-01    Yes
  b    2001-01-01    Yes    
  c    2002-01-01    Yes
```

Any ideas on how to manipulate this query to return what is expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to `LEFT JOIN` the first table to the second one, and then check each record in the first table to see whether its `ID` matched anything in the second table.

```
SELECT t1.Name,
       t1.Date,
       CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Yes/No]
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

By using LEFT JOIN and checking using CASE if there is no matching result on the second table (t2.ID IS NULL), you can easily get what you need as below:

```
 SELECT Name, Date, CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [Yes/No]
 FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation for the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * , case when exists(select 1 from Table2 as b where b.ID = a.ID and b.Name = a.Name) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as 'Yes/No'
From table1 as a
```

Your query:

```
DECLARE @boolean as varchar(10)
IF EXISTS(
SELECT ID FROM Table 2
)
SET @boolean = 'Yes'
```

will always return true because you only check whether `ID` exists (which always exists records in `table2`), you forgot to check that should be the `ID` exists in `table1`, and you probably do not do in that way, because the indicator is a dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

If a `left join` might return multiple unwanted results you can use [**`outer apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) instead:

```
select t1.*, [Yes/No]=coalesce(x.Yes,'No')
from table_1 t1
  outer apply (
    select Yes='Yes'
    from table_2 t2
    where t1.id = t2.id
    ) x
```